# How i fetch comma separate email from system.xml

Tags: magento2, email

This is my system.xml file

```
ScheduleContentNotifier\etc\adminhtml\system.xml
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="custommodule" translate="label">           
            <label>Custom Module</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="content" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="600" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Schedule Content Notifier</label>
            <tab>custommodule</tab>
            <resource>custommodule_ScheduleContentNotifier::notifier</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Email</label>
                <field id="email" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Enter Email</label>
                    <comment>Enter comma-separated emails for notifying when scheduled content goes live.</comment>
                </field>            
            </group>
            <group id="update" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Please Choose Your Email Template</label>
                <field id="template" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Email Template</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template</source_model>
                    <comment>Email template is chosen based on theme fallback when "Default" option is selected.</comment>
                </field>            
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

This is my helper file

```
ScheduleContentNotifier\Helper\Email.php
```

```
<?php
namespace Custommodule\ScheduleContentNotifier\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class Email extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $inlineTranslation;
    protected $escaper;
    protected $transportBuilder;
    protected $logger;
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        Escaper $escaper,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->escaper = $escaper;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->logger = $context->getLogger();
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function sendEmail()
    {
        try {
            $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
            $sender = [
                'name' => $this->escaper->escapeHtml('example'),
                'email' => $this->escaper->escapeHtml($this->scopeConfig->getValue('content/general/email')),
            ];
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier('content_update_template')
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                    ]
                )->setTemplateVars([])
                ->setFrom($sender)
                ->addTo($sender)
                ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->debug($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you already have the email field defined in the `system.xml` file under the content/general group. To fetch the comma-separated email addresses from the configuration, you can modify your helper file as follows:

```
<?php
namespace Custommodule\ScheduleContentNotifier\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class Email extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $inlineTranslation;
    protected $escaper;
    protected $transportBuilder;
    protected $logger;
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        Context              $context,
        StateInterface       $inlineTranslation,
        Escaper              $escaper,
        TransportBuilder     $transportBuilder,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->escaper = $escaper;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->logger = $context->getLogger();
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }
    
    public function sendEmail()
    {
        try {
            $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();

            // Fetch comma-separated emails from system.xml configuration
            $emails = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('content/general/email');

            // Split the emails into an array
            $emailArray = explode(',', $emails);

            $sender = [
                'name' => $this->escaper->escapeHtml('example'),
                'email' => $this->escaper->escapeHtml(trim($emailArray[0])), // Use the first email address in the array
            ];

            $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier('content_update_template')
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                    ]
                )->setTemplateVars([])
                ->setFrom($sender)
                ->addTo($sender)
                ->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->debug($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

- In the `sendEmail()` method, we retrieve the comma-separated email addresses from the configuration using `$emails = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('content/general/email')`. Then we explode the $emails string into an array using `$emailArray = explode(',', $emails)`. Finally, we use the first email address from the array as the sender's email address.

**Note:** In the code above, I have used `$emailArray[0]` to retrieve the first email address from the array. You can modify the logic according to your specific requirements if you need to handle multiple email addresses differently.

Comment: thank you @charmipatel